# How to get resulting ImageView size in Glide after photo has been loaded

Tags: android, android-glide

I need to retrieve the resulting ImageView size after loading an image with Glide. This is what I have tried so far:

```
Glide.with(context).load(ULTRAWIDE_PHOTO_ASSET).transition(DrawableTransitionOptions.withCrossFade()).into(imageview)
.getSize(new SizeReadyCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onSizeReady(int width, int height) {
        Log.d("DIMENSIONS X", "anchor " + width);
        Log.d("DIMENSIONS Y", "anchor " + height);
    }
});
```

These are the dimensions I'm getting 2094x2094, but the photo and the resulting ImageView are definitely not square (it has more of a 2:1 aspect). Additionally, calling imageView.getWidth() , imageView.getHeight() inside the callback returns 0.0.

How can I get the resulting dimensions. I need to do some postprocessing with them.